# PDF Extractor with Flutter or Python

Tags: python, flutter, dart

I've try extract text from PDF file and run it on my Flutter project.

I've start with Python and it work beautifully but while I want run it in my project with [Starflut](https://pub.dev/packages/starflut).. Project doesn't run, so ok, I try with [Syncfusion_pdf_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf#extract-text) and him just take 10% of the page, I don't know what to do and it's why I ask if someone had the same problem. Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question, if you need python script for get data, you need to create Flask project, see the both videos [Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6AwCCvGC58&t=125s) [Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXB3gap6P8k&t=240s)